# js find min difference in date array

Tags: javascript

I have a sorted array:

```
[new Date('2017-01-02'), new Date('2017-01-07'), new Date('2017-01-09'), new Date('2017-01-17')]
```

Now I want to find the minimum time difference occuring in the array between any two adjacent elements. eg in this case:

```
new Date('2017-01-09').getTime() - new Date('2017-01-07').getTime()
```

is there some elegant way with map or something similar or do I have to loop, remember the smalles interval so far and then replace the value if a smaller one occurs?

Current solution:

```
 let timestamps = Gps.find().map(doc => doc.timestamp);
                    timestamps.sort();
                    let minimumDifference;
                    let previousTimestamp;
                    timestamps.forEach(timestamp => {
                        if(!previousTimestamp) {
                            previousTimestamp = timestamp;
                        }
                        else{
                            let difference = timestamp.getTime() - previousTimestamp.getTime();
                            if(!minimumDifference || minimumDifference > difference){
                                minimumDifference = difference;
                            }
                            previousTimestamp = timestamp;
                        }

                    });
```

Comment: I have to say, I am rather a fan of a simple loop solution in situations like this ... that is easily readable and self-explanatory, whereas chained and nested map/filter/whatever calls are more often rather voodoo-istic. And I don’t think mapping works to well in situations where you need access to other array elements as well, and not only the current one. Maybe that can be achieved ... but I doubt it will look much “prettier” in the end.

Comment: So unless you have a situation where performance becomes an issue due to a huge amount of data (where “native” functionality to go over the array elements might be a little faster than an explicit loop), I would not bother to find something else, if what you got is working for you. (In that regard - what would be the expected outcome, if you have two or more intervals of the same minimal length in your array?)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go back into olden days. plain old javascript. Not creating unnecessory copy

```
var timestamps = [1,2,5,9];
timestamps.sort();
var result = timestamps[timestamps.length-1];
for(var i=1;i<timestamps.length;i++){
   result = (timestamps[i]-timestamps[i-1])<result?(timestamps[i]-timestamps[i-1]):result;
}
```

take mills and proceed same way